# How can I remove superficial pet urine stains from subfloor?

Tags: cleaning, flooring, carpet, odors

After removing the carpet from our bathroom closet, I found urine stains on the plywood sub-floor (serenity now).

It sounds bad but the floors are quite sturdy so I'm reasonably certain that it's a superficial stain.  What would be the recommended way of cleaning it (short of removing/replacing the sub-floor).

I'm planning to eventually place carpeting back in the closet so I'm not concerned with leaving a mark.  Just want to make sure it's sanitary and odor-free.

-M

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [Zep pet spotter](http://www.homedepot.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?jspStoreDir=hdus&catalogId=10053&productId=100155375&navFlow=3&keyword=736945&langId=-1&searchRedirect=736945&storeId=10051&endecaDataBean=com.homedepot.sa.el.wc.integration.endeca.EndecaDataBean%403a14b558&ddkey=Search), but it's intended for carpets, not wood.  I think mop it with a dilute solution of chlorine bleach to sanitize the area, then seal it with a [primer / sealer](http://www.homedepot.com/h_d1/N-5yc1vZ1xh8/R-100398381/h_d2/ProductDisplay?langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10053) to prevent any residual odors from escaping.

Comment: Just an update -- primer/sealer seemed to work the best after trying a variety of different cleaning products. Thanks!

Comment: I've heard that cleaning with bleach can actually encourage animals to use this area again.

Answer (score 3):

What you want to look for are cleaners that are enzyme cleaners.  These products actually break down the urine/biological waste.  One example (that I use quite often) is [Nature's Miracle](http://www.naturemakesitwork.com/home/index.php).

Answer (score 2):

I just love [Nok Out](http://www.nokout.ca/).

I successfully removed cat urine odors from furniture, matresses and laminated flooring with it.

Answer (score 1):

I would try oxygen bleach, in particular Stainsolver - see stainsolver.com. I'm not selling it, and in no way associated with it other than being a happy customer.